# How to run\handle multiple Ruby on Rails applications on the same domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I have an application running at the `www.mywebsitename.com` domain. For improvement reasons I would like to run my application at the `www.uk.mywebsitename.com` subdomain (BTW: at the `www.mywebsitename.com` domain I will run a RoR application to redirect users to the proper subdomain).

I do not need geocoding or similar. Simply, I would like to know how to run my application on the `www.uk.mywebsitename.com` Web address (I am planning to add as subdomain other/similar RoR applications like `www.de.mywebsitename.com` and `www.it.mywebsitename.com`, *each working with a separate database*): **what I have to care/do? what do you advice about?**

*P.S.*: My server is running Linux Ubuntu and Apache. I deploy with the Capistrano gem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for how to make apache vhosts, since that's basically what they do.

I assume you're using phusion passenger, and in that case you should already have one vhost (or at least a default site in `/etc/apache/sites-available` (or something similar, it might be `apache2`, I'm not entirely sure).

What you basically need to do to get multiple rails applications working is to set up one vhost for each rails application and set the proper `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` for each vhost.

It might look something like this for you uk site:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.uk.mywebsitename.com
  DocumentRoot /path/to/where/your/uk/site/is/deployed/current/public
  <Directory /path/to/where/your/uk/site/is/deployed/current/public>
    Allow from all
    Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

How to setup vhosts for passenger is documented [in the passenger documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2).